# Inserting gdb breakpoints fail

Tags: c, assembly, gdb

I'm learning about buffer overflow in c.
For that purpose, I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJ8IwyhqzD4&t=88s) simple example.

I have the following gcc version:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And this simple c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buf[256];
    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
    printf("%s,", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

I then compile this file with  `$ gcc buf.c -o buf`.
I then open in gdb by `$ gdb ./buf`

I call disas and get the result assembly:

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001189 <+0>:     endbr64 
   0x000000000000118d <+4>:     push   %rbp
   0x000000000000118e <+5>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000001191 <+8>:     sub    $0x120,%rsp
   0x0000000000001198 <+15>:    mov    %edi,-0x114(%rbp)
   0x000000000000119e <+21>:    mov    %rsi,-0x120(%rbp)
   0x00000000000011a5 <+28>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x00000000000011ae <+37>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000000011b2 <+41>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x00000000000011b4 <+43>:    mov    -0x120(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000000011bb <+50>:    add    $0x8,%rax
   0x00000000000011bf <+54>:    mov    (%rax),%rdx
   0x00000000000011c2 <+57>:    lea    -0x110(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000000011c9 <+64>:    mov    %rdx,%rsi
   0x00000000000011cc <+67>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x00000000000011cf <+70>:    callq  0x1070 <strcpy@plt>
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
   0x00000000000011d4 <+75>:    lea    -0x110(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000000011db <+82>:    mov    %rax,%rsi
   0x00000000000011de <+85>:    lea    0xe1f(%rip),%rdi        # 0x2004
   0x00000000000011e5 <+92>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000000011ea <+97>:    callq  0x1090 <printf@plt>
   0x00000000000011ef <+102>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000000011f4 <+107>:   mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rcx
   0x00000000000011f8 <+111>:   xor    %fs:0x28,%rcx
   0x0000000000001201 <+120>:   je     0x1208 <main+127>
   0x0000000000001203 <+122>:   callq  0x1080 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
   0x0000000000001208 <+127>:   leaveq 
   0x0000000000001209 <+128>:   retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

With some really low memory adresses.
I then want to see what happens if I input a big string of A's into the program, I therefore place a breakpoint at `0x00000000000011db`
I then run it:

```
(gdb) run $(python3 -c "print('A'*256)"
Starting program: /home/ask/Notes/ctf/bufoverflow/code/buf $(python3 -c "print('A'*256)"
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
During startup program exited with code 1.
(gdb) run $(python3 -c "print('A'*256)")
Starting program: /home/ask/Notes/ctf/bufoverflow/code/buf $(python3 -c "print('A'*256)")
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x11db
```

Ok, so something with the memory adresses is a bit funky.
I google the issue and find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819704/cannot-insert-breakpoints-addresses-with-low-values) where I find that this is because Position-Independent Executable (PIE) was probably enabled, and the memory adresses would be changed when the program is actually run.
I can confirm this by running disas after running the program, and seeing that the memory adresses are in a lot higher ranges.

This all makes sense, but it makes me wonder, iif the adresses change every time I run it, then how can I then place a breakpoint at a memory adress before the program runs?

Comment: If you enable debug symbols you can do `b main`, `start` or `b some-line-number`. Alternatively you can do `starti` which stops at the first instruction and then you can place your breakpoints to the resolved addresses. You can also disable ASLR so addresses don't change between runs.

Comment: tx a lot! however, I'm a bit unsure about the commands there. I can't find anything for `starti`, I'm not sure what b is in this context, or whast enabling debugging symbols entails

Comment: ["The starti command does the equivalent of setting a temporary breakpoint at the first instruction of a program’s execution and then invoking the run command."](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html) `b` is an abbreviation for `break` that you know :) You can enable debug info by `gcc -g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> iif the adresses change every time I run it, then how can I then place a breakpoint at a memory adress before the program runs?

This happens because GDB by default disables address randomization (to make debugging easier).

If you re-enable ASLR with `(gdb) set disable-randomization off`, then you wouldn't be able to set the breakpoint on an address.

You would still be able to set breakpoint on e.g. `main` -- in that case GDB will wait until the executable has been relocated, and will set the breakpoint on the actual runtime instruction (the address will change on every run).

Comment: Or even at `main+37` for example to set a bp at a specific instruction inside the function.  Note that `b main` will try to set the breakpoint after the function prologue; `b *main` will avoid that, if that works for delayed setting of breakpoints.