# Breakpoint not set executing a program on Linux under control of GDB

Tags: linux, gdb, shared-libraries, executable, breakpoints

I'm debugging via gdb a simple "hello world" program under Linux 4.15 & gcc version 7.5.0. The ELF excutable is built simply using `gcc main.c -o main`.

Now when I execute it under the control of gdb I can see the disassemble of main

```
root@ubuntu:/root# gdb -q ./main 
Reading symbols from ./main...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) disassemble main 
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000000000000063a <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x000000000000063b <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000000063e <+4>:     lea    0x9f(%rip),%rdi        # 0x6e4
   0x0000000000000645 <+11>:    callq  0x510 <puts@plt>
   0x000000000000064a <+16>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000000000000064f <+21>:    pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000000650 <+22>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

As you can see the addresses of the main code seem to be just *offsets* and not real addresses where the code is actually loaded in process'virtual address space, indeed:

```
(gdb) info files 
Symbols from "/root/main".
Local exec file:
        `/root/main', file type elf64-x86-64.
        Entry point: 0x530
        0x0000000000000238 - 0x0000000000000254 is .interp
        0x0000000000000254 - 0x0000000000000274 is .note.ABI-tag
        0x0000000000000274 - 0x0000000000000298 is .note.gnu.build-id
        0x0000000000000298 - 0x00000000000002b4 is .gnu.hash
        0x00000000000002b8 - 0x0000000000000360 is .dynsym
        0x0000000000000360 - 0x00000000000003e2 is .dynstr
        0x00000000000003e2 - 0x00000000000003f0 is .gnu.version
        0x00000000000003f0 - 0x0000000000000410 is .gnu.version_r
        0x0000000000000410 - 0x00000000000004d0 is .rela.dyn
        0x00000000000004d0 - 0x00000000000004e8 is .rela.plt
        0x00000000000004e8 - 0x00000000000004ff is .init
        0x0000000000000500 - 0x0000000000000520 is .plt
        0x0000000000000520 - 0x0000000000000528 is .plt.got
        0x0000000000000530 - 0x00000000000006d2 is .text
        0x00000000000006d4 - 0x00000000000006dd is .fini
        0x00000000000006e0 - 0x00000000000006f1 is .rodata
        0x00000000000006f4 - 0x0000000000000730 is .eh_frame_hdr
        0x0000000000000730 - 0x0000000000000838 is .eh_frame
        0x0000000000200db8 - 0x0000000000200dc0 is .init_array
        0x0000000000200dc0 - 0x0000000000200dc8 is .fini_array
        0x0000000000200dc8 - 0x0000000000200fb8 is .dynamic
        0x0000000000200fb8 - 0x0000000000201000 is .got
        0x0000000000201000 - 0x0000000000201010 is .data
        0x0000000000201010 - 0x0000000000201018 is .bss
(gdb)
```

At the same time I cannot set breakpoint on it, e.g.

```
(gdb) break *0x510
Breakpoint 1 at 0x510
(gdb) r
Starting program: /root/main 
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x510

(gdb)
```

Can you help me in understanding why ? Thanks.

Comment: Looks very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50819704/1983398).

Comment: Apart from dynamic linking/binding process, are all the shared libraries referenced by an executable loaded inside the process's address space _before_ the execution begin ?